# Drawing ellipses over a tile map server in PyQGIS?

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis, ellipse

I have a few ellipses, defined by a latitude, longitude, semi-major axis in nautical miles, semi-minor axis in nautical miles, and an orientation. I'm trying to render them over a Google Maps layer.

I create the QgsEllipse:

```
def qgs_ellipse(self):
    return QgsEllipse(QgsPoint(self.latitude, self.longitude), self.semi_major_axis, self.semi_minor_axis, self.orientation)
```

Create the QgsFeature:

```
def qgs_feature(self):
    feature = QgsFeature()
    feature.setGeometry(self.qgs_ellipse().toPolygon())
    return feature
```

Create a QgsRasterLayer from a Google Maps TMS:

```
self.tms_layer = QgsRasterLayer("type=xyz&url=" + tms[1], tms[0], "wms")
self.project.addMapLayer(self.tms_layer)
```

Create the QgsVectorLayer:

```
self.ellipse_layer = QgsVectorLayer("polygon", "Ellipses", "memory")
self.ellipse_provider = self.ellipse_layer.dataProvider()
self.project.addMapLayer(self.ellipse_layer)
```

Add the ellipses to the vector layer:

```
def add_ellipses(self, ellipses):
    features = []
    for ellipse in ellipses:
        features.append(ellipse.qgs_feature())
    self.ellipse_provider.addFeatures(features)
```

And finally add the layers to the QgsMapCanvas:

```
self.canvas.setLayers([self.ellipse_layer, self.tms_layer])
self.canvas.setExtent(self.ellipse_layer.extent())
self.canvas.show()
```

The issue is that all the ellipses show up in the center of the map, all centered on the same point. I also don't know if I need to convert the ellipse axis' from nautical miles to something else.

Is there a coordinate system or something I need to set up?

I am pretty new to GIS.